# Loop Displaying Filename JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of file names. When displayed in my console log, the array looks like below:

```
Array
(
[0] => s/a/1.png
[1] => s/a/2.png
[2] => s/a/3.png
)
```

I need to get the file names again to display in another page, so I looped through the array but I get each element at each line. So it looks like this:

> [
>  0
> ]
>  =
> >
> so on.

Any idea how to fix that?

Here is the code:

```
function loadSlideShow(images){
    var text="";
    for(var i=0; i<images.length;i++){
        text += images[i]. + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile and so it can't produce the output you described. Please update the question with the part in which you fill the array and with the actual loadSlideShow function

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not properly defined. Try:

```
var images = ['s/a/1.png', 's/a/2.png', 's/a/3.png'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems in your code:

1. There is a dot (`.`) after `images[i]` and before the `+` that I think doesn't make any sense and even the compiler cannot understand. So I don't know how you are getting wrong results when this doesn't even compile. I'm talking about this line: `text += images[i]. + "<br>";`
2. You are assigning the `innerHTML` of the "`try`" element on each iteration. And you are also concatenating the results. So probably you should move that line after the for loop.

But fixing any of those probably won't save your from your current problem you are describing. I suppose that would be because you might failed at copying the code that actually has the problem.

I suppose the problem might be on the initialization of the array as kaz said.

But please **check your code and update the question with the minimal code sample that fails** exactly as you describe.

Comment: that is my problem. Im not sure how to get the filenames from the array of images.

Comment: I'm not talking about you trying to fix the function. You can also do that and post the answer here if you like. But what I ask you to do is to check that your code in the question matches exactly to the code you are running. Because the code in the question is not compiling so it's not posible it generates the problem you are describing. So please copy-paste the your code in the question again. And make sure to include the part in which you define the array. And try to use proper indentation this time (so is easy for other programmers to read).